# Self Join scenario in spring data elastic seach

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

How to search self referencing documents in elastic search?

```
public class ProductDocument {
@Id
private String id;
private String title;
private List<String> tags;
//private List<ProductDocument> relatedProducts -- Doesn't work
private List<String> relatedProducts;
}
```

So while searching i want to perform operations like

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "cloths", 
      "fields": [ "title", "tags", "relatedProducts.title", "relatedProducts.tags" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

```
Sample DataSet:
id     title     tags       relatedProducts
1.     Book       null        null
2.      WM.       cloths.     1
3.      cloths.                2

Output:
id     title     tags       relatedProducts
2.      WM.       cloths.      1
3.      cloths.                2
```

How can this be achieved? I searched around and found nothing so far. any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Could you please provide sample data set and from that what is your expected output.

Comment: @Sagar Patel updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Need to use a nested type

```
public class ProductDocument {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String title;
  private List<String> tags;

  // Use the nested datatype for the related products field
  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
  private List<ProductDocument> relatedProducts;
}
```

Then, when you perform a search, you can use the nested query to search for matches in the related products field. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "relatedProducts",
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query": "cloths", 
          "fields": ["title", "tags"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem was how to create document itself. Do we keep  whole document or Just the Id's in the relatedProducts?

Comment: I guess there are two options. Store the entire ProductDocument in relatedProducts or store just the id of the related ProductDocument objects in relatedProducts. Storing just the id would likely result in faster indexing and search performance along with smaller documents. Storing the entire ProductDocument would allow you to search by any of the ProductDocument fields. I guess it depends on the amount of Product documents you will storing.

Comment: But if we just store id how am i going to search on title and tags of related products. My problem is I want to store just Ids but search on fields much like how we do in RDBMS